# ProgressDialog not showing up despite show() is called

Tags: android, progress-bar, show

I've got a strange problem, a Dialog being created and called for "show()" but not being visible in my activity...

The thing is it goes through the call "show", I've seen it in the debugger, but nothing...

here is the code:

```
    protected void initializeSpinners() {
    spnPlayLists = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnLists);
    spnProviders = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnProvider);
    spnProviders.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> _spinner, View _parent,
                int _pos, long _id) {
            if (_spinner == spnProviders) {
                String[] playListsId = core.getAllPlayListsFrom(_pos);
                int items = playListsId.length;
                **showProgressDialog(items);**
                String[] playListsNames = new String[items];
                String[] playListsThumbs = new String[items];
                playLists = new PlayList[items];
                for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
                    String id = playListsId[i];
                    PlayList playList = core.getPlayList(id, true);
                    playLists[i] = playList;
                    playListsNames[i] = playList.title;
                    playListsThumbs[i] = playList.thumb;
                    handle.sendEmptyMessage(i);
                }
                loadPlayLists(playListsNames, playListsThumbs);
                myPd_bar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> _arg0) {
        }

    });

    ProvidersArrayAdapter providersAdapter = new ProvidersArrayAdapter(this);
    spnProviders.setAdapter(providersAdapter);
}
```

and the function called up:

```
    private void showProgressDialog(int _items) {
    handle = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            myPd_bar.setProgress(msg.what + 1);
        }
    };

    myPd_bar = new ProgressDialog(Intro.this);
    myPd_bar.setMessage("Loading....");
    myPd_bar.setTitle("Please Wait..");
    myPd_bar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    myPd_bar.setProgress(0);
    myPd_bar.setMax(_items);
    **myPd_bar.show();**
}
```

what am I doing bad...?

Comment: I don't know much about the ProgressDialog but maybe try `myPd_bar.create().show();`. Not sure if the `.create()` is needed here or not...

Comment: Is not even allowed! :) thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, I also found out this very morning that `.show()` will create the dialog and show all in one! So in this instance `.create()` would be unnecessary. The way that I have used dialogs I had never come across a time that just using .show() without .create would have been that much better so I've never known that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I realized. I was holding the activity thread in the spinner so it won't show anything until it finishes!

here is my solution, using an asyntask (properly, I was using them badly on the playlist load, and blocking)

```
protected void setupDialog() {
    handle = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.what < 0){
                loadPlayLists(playListsNames, playListsThumbs);
                myPd_bar.dismiss();
            } else {
                myPd_bar.setProgress(msg.what + 1);
            }
        }
    };

    myPd_bar = new ProgressDialog(Intro.this);
    myPd_bar.setMessage(WAIT_MESSAGE);
    myPd_bar.setTitle(WAIT_TITLE);
    myPd_bar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    myPd_bar.setProgress(0);
}

protected void initializeSpinners() {
    spnPlayLists = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnLists);
    spnProviders = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnProvider);
    spnProviders.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> _spinner, View _parent,
                int _pos, long _id) {
            if (_spinner == spnProviders) {
                String[] playListsId = core.getAllPlayListsFrom(_pos);
                int items = playListsId.length;
                myPd_bar.setMax(items);
                myPd_bar.show();
                new AsyncTask<String[], Integer, Long>(){

                    @Override
                    protected Long doInBackground(String[]... _playListsId) {
                        int items = _playListsId[0].length;
                        playListsNames = new String[items];
                        playListsThumbs = new String[items];
                        playLists = new PlayList[items];
                        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
                            String id = _playListsId[0][i];
                            PlayList playList = core.getPlayList(id, true);
                            playLists[i] = playList;
                            playListsNames[i] = playList.title;
                            playListsThumbs[i] = playList.thumb;
                            publishProgress(i);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... _progress) {
                        handle.sendEmptyMessage(_progress[0]);
                     }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Long _result) {
                        handle.sendEmptyMessage(-1);
                     }
                }.execute(playListsId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> _arg0) {
        }

    });

    ProvidersArrayAdapter providersAdapter = new ProvidersArrayAdapter(this);
    spnProviders.setAdapter(providersAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your dialog is getting dismissed before it appears. Basically your loop is not going long enough for the view to appear.

Have you tried to comment out the dismiss line and see if it appear then?

Comment: It doesn't appear at all, while debugging, I loop like 10 times and have a breakpoint at the handle message but nothing.

Comment: like I said did you try to comment out `myPd_bar.dismiss();`? You should also be using a `DialogFragment` to do this.

Comment: Sorry tycj, because the activity was blocked for a while I didn't try it. Now I try it and... something really strange happens. It shows up but when it has finished, not from the beginning, not when I ask it to.... It shows up when it is complete!

Why should I use the dialogfragment instead? This one is the exact functionality I need, and if I use fragments the App is not suitable for under 3.0 versions...

thanks again

Comment: fragments are suitable for applications under 3.0 you use the support library. With the support library the use of the dialogfragment is the preferred way to show dialogs

Comment: oh! thanks for the advice, I'll do that :) given that it doesn't look like solvable...